# How to modify a global variable in bash function while catching stdout output and also return a valid return code?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, substitution

In bash programming I am currently facing a problem where I do not only want to modify a global variable in a bash function but also return a proper return code via `return` and `$?` as well as being able to assign all `stdout` output which appears during the function call to a variable outside of the function.

While each of these individual tasks (modify global var, return status code, assign stdout to variable) seems to perfectly possible in bash (and even a combination of two of these wishes), a combination of all the three requirements seems to be hardly (i.e. only inconveniently) possible.

Here is an example script I have prepared to demonstrate the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This is the required output:
#
# -- cut here --
# RETURN: '2'
# OUTPUT: 'Hello World!'
# GLOBAL_VAR: '3'
# -- cut here --
#

GLOBAL_VAR=0

hello() {
  echo "Hello World!"
  GLOBAL_VAR=3
  return 2
}

# (1) normal bash command substition (subshell)
#     PROBLEM: GLOBAL_VAR is 0 but should be 3
#              (hello is executed in subshell)
#
output=$(hello) ; result=$?

# (2) use 'read' and a reverse pipe
#     PROBLEM: RETURN and GLOBAL_VAR is 0
#              (hello in subshell and read return
#               code returned)
#
#read output < <(hello) ; result=$?

# (3) normal function execution
#     PROBLEM: no catched output!
#
#hello ; result=$?

# (4) using lastpipe + read
#     PROBLEM: GLOBAL_VAR is 0 but should be 3
#              (a pipe generateѕ a subshell?!?!)
#
#shopt -s lastpipe
#hello | read output ; result=${PIPESTATUS[0]}

# (5) ksh-like command substiution
#     PROBLEM: Works, but ksh-syntax 
#              -> doesn't work in bash!
#
#output=${ hello; } ; result=$?

# (6) using a temp file to catch output of hello()
#     WORKS, but ugly due to tmpfile and 2xsubshell use!
#
#tmp=$(mktemp)
#hello >${tmp} ; result=$?
#output=$(cat ${tmp})
#rm -f ${tmp}

###################################
# OUTPUT stuff

# this should output "2"
echo "RESULT: '${result}'"

# this should output "Hello World!"
echo "OUTPUT: '$output'"

# this should output "3"
echo "GLOBAL_VAR: '$GLOBAL_VAR'"
```

In this script I have added a function `hello()` which should return a status code of 2, sets a global variable `GLOBAL_VAR` to 3 and outputs "Hello World!" to `stdout`. 
In addition to this function I have added 6 potential solutions to call this `hello()` function to achieve exactly the output I require (which is shown at the top of the bash script code).

By commenting out/in these 6 different ways of calling the function you will see that only solution (6) is possible to fulfill all my requirements for calling the function.

Especially interesting is that solution number (5) shows the ksh-syntax which works exactly like I require this function to work. So calling this script using `ksh` outputs all variables with their required values. Of course this solution (command substitution using `${ cmd; }`) isn't supported in bash. However, I definitely require a bash solution as the main script where I require my solution is a bash-only script I cannot port to ksh.

While of course, solution (6) also fulfills my requirements it requires to put the output of `hello()` in a temporary file and read it afterwards again. In terms of performance (several subshells required, temp-file management) this isn't a real solution for me.

So now the question comes up if there is any other potential solution in bash that fulfills my requirements so that the script above outputs exactly what I want, thus combines all my three requirements?!?

Comment: I would use solution #6

Comment: If the performance hit in #6 is an actual problem, `bash` is probably not the right language for this program.

Comment: I think you should redesign the solution in a way that you don't need to set the global var out of that function.

Comment: I really just wonder myself why bash doesn't support what ksh does? To me it seems to be totally logical that this case might be valid and someone just wants to catch the output of a function call not being executed in a subshell. And as it seems this is hardly possible with bash.

Comment: bash doesn't work like ksh because it's not ksh. bash was implemented differently with different design goals

Comment: @JensMaus I've not a deep insight into ksh but in a few tests it behaved like bash. Meaning if you store the output of a function into a variable - using command substitution, it will run in a subshell. If you touch global variables in that subshell, those changes will of course not affect the main shell.

Comment: @hek2mgl But as I have outlined above, there is a possibility to call a function like `output=${ hello; }` and it will behave exactly I would expect it. To me this really seems to be a shortcoming of bash as it seems rather logical that you want to have an easy possibility to catch stdout output from a function which you don't want to start in a dedicated sub-shell. Currently bash doesn't provide you this functionality but forces you to use a subshell call like `$(hello)`

Comment: @JensMaus Thanks, I've learned something. Having the possibility to run `output={ command }` where `command` does not need to run in a subshell might be nice sometimes.

Comment: However, I'm still with my general advice that a shell program might be rewritten in a way that it does not need to do that things or a programming language which does support complex data structures [ and classes ] should be used.

Comment: @hek2mgl Of course, I could rewrite my bash script to e.g. not require to modify the global variable but my initial question was/is simply if there might be something I might have missing in bash programming which solves the issues I am outlining here.

Comment: @JensMaus Don't get me wrong, the question itself is good, especially since you showed that it is possible using ksh. Maybe you should search trough mailing list archives and or feature requests of bash to check if this has been discussed before.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question why you can't simply rewrite the function to behave differently.  If you really can't change the function, you could change bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

GLOBAL_VAR=0

hello() {
  echo "Hello World!" 
  GLOBAL_VAR=3
  return 2
}

echo ()  { output=$*; }
hello
result=$?
unset -f echo

# this should output "2"
echo "RESULT: '$result'"

# this should output "Hello World!"
echo "OUTPUT: '$output'"

# this should output "3"
echo "GLOBAL_VAR: '$GLOBAL_VAR'"
```

The outputs match the expectations.